# Javascript - Count the number of replaced strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I properly count the amount of replaced strings in Javascript. For some reason the increment function below gives me "0" instead of "2".

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa6wgpbf/)

```
  var input = "A B C A";

  function Replace(str) {
    return str.replace(/A/g, "1");
    Counter();
  }

  var increment = 0;

  function Counter() {
    increment++;
  }

  alert(Replace(input)); // 1 B C 1
  alert(increment); // 2
```

Comment: `return` exits the function. `Counter` is never called.

Comment: Even if it were, it would only be called **once**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

KISS, You can use a function in the replacement part of `replace` function. There you can increase the counter value.

```js
var input = "A B C A";
var count = 0;
console.log(input.replace(/A/g, function(x){count+=1;return "1"}))
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I see you have already accepted a solution. This is a bit of a pity since our answer 1 to 1 has the same content and I posted my answer about 10 min earlier anyway. Well, as always, that's your decision.*

**Have a look at a working solution!**

So you can count the amount of **replaces** using this simple code:

```js
var number = 0;
var string = "A B C A"

document.body.innerHTML = string.replace(/A/g, function() {
                     // will be called if a "A" gets found
    number++;        // increases count of "number"
    return "1"       // return will replace "A" with "1"
});
console.log(number)  // result will be "2" (because "A" gots found 2times)
```

Comment: Edited :) @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Recommend **not** using boldface unnecessarily (your first paragraph), just let the designers of the site handle default styling.

Comment: @SebastianJ at the very first, you posted a different  solution. Actually You copied my solution and added it to your answer and deleted the old one. Now you shouting it as yours,,

Comment: This is **absolutely** not true, so sadly you are a lier. Mhm, however - so I don't care about the single up vote / correct mark, please just have fun with :) @AvinashRaj

Comment: Am I a **lier**? See, I have lot of reps in my pocket, why I have to copy another one's answer? At the time of answering you and another guy posts a different solution.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49347298/1 , here you posted two ways 2nd one is your original answer (and you added 1way within 5 mins), later you added first one after my answer itself.

Comment: Use user9511492 posted first, but without callback and code that doesn't actually work. Then @Avinash Raj posted the correct solution, and then user9511492 edited his answer to include callback (which is the same as Avinash Raj solution).

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "A B C A";

  function Replace(str) {
    Counter();
    return str.replace(/A/g, "1");

  }

  var increment = 0;

  function Counter() {
    increment++;
  }

  alert(Replace(input)); // 1 B C 1
  alert(increment); // 2
```

Counter() should be called before return statement.